# Cart Total prices are not updating

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

**Hello There! I am trying to update Cart Total Prices of my ecommerce app. I have tried to add functionality but its not adding and updating the price. Pleased check my code and help thank you.**   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBfwY.png)

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

```
import 'cart_modal.dart';

class UserModel {
  static const ID = "uid";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const EMAIL = "email";
  static const STRIPE_ID = "stripeId";
  static const CART = "cart";

  String _name;
  String _email;
  String _id;
  String _stripeId;
  String _priceSum = '0';

//  getters
  String get name => _name;

  String get email => _email;

  String get id => _id;

  String get stripeId => _stripeId;

  // public variables
  List<CartItemModel> cart;
  String totalCartPrice;

  UserModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    _name = doc.data()[NAME];
    _email = doc.data()[EMAIL];
    _id = doc.data()[ID];
    cart = _convertCartItems(doc.data()[CART] ?? []);
    totalCartPrice = getTotalPrice(cart: doc.data()[CART]);

    _stripeId = doc.data()[STRIPE_ID] ?? '';
  }

  List<CartItemModel> _convertCartItems(List cart) {
    List<CartItemModel> convertedCart = [];
    for (Map cartItem in cart) {
      convertedCart.add(CartItemModel.fromMap(cartItem));
    }
    return convertedCart;
  }

  String getTotalPrice({List cart}) {
    if (cart == null) {
      return '0';
    }
    for (Map cartItem in cart) {
      _priceSum += cartItem["price"];
    }

    String total = _priceSum;
    return total;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not update because you have created a data type of total as a `String`.
and two `string` variables can't be added because they are treated as a text not as a number. You need to convert them into the `integer value` to make the addition happen.

Simply you can declare variable `_priceSum` as `int _priceSum`.
and also if your `cartItem["price"]` is a string value then you need to convert it at the time of calculation. you can do it by parsing as shown below
`int.parse(cartItem["price"])`

so your for loop will look like

```
 for (Map cartItem in cart) {
      _priceSum += int.parse(cartItem["price"])
    }
```

and also you have to convert your final result into string again so you will not get any error.

`String total = _priceSum.toString();`

Comment: hello sir ! I hope you are doing well, actually I have posted 2 -3 queries on stack but no one is replying. I need your help you are the only person who have helped me solving my queries , I am new to flutter Please help me out. I will waiting for your response . Thank you.

Comment: There are so many people to help you. if you are on telegram join this flutter community : https://t.me/FlutterIndia . I can't see questions in your profile.